# composer failed to read C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin

Tags: windows, laravel-5, composer-php

I am using laravel 5.2 in windows 10 using xampp and trying this command to work in git bash but every time it shows up with an error

[RuntimeException]
  Could not read C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
  file_get_contents(C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin): failed to open stream:
   Permission denied

Comment: As it says *Permission denied*! Means your user has no permissions to access that folder. Check the permissions for that folder in Windows.

Comment: i have changed the permissions but still having the same error

Comment: actually i am wirking on laravel and using windows 10. i was trying to use homestead but i failed. i dont know why but my virtual box was not working accurately then i decide to use xampp but still a want to use homestead if you can assist me

Comment: did it work on your plain old cmd?

Comment: no it did not work on plain cmd :( same error Could not read C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin